# Effect with Jquery don't works

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building these web sites: www.watersandstudio.com/test (is a test) and I would like to know why my effects do not start.(i have a particles.js and a portfolio section)

They only run if you resize your browser window. (i tested with all browsers)

Thanks in advance

Particle.js

```
particlesJS("particles-js", {
  "particles": {
    "number": {
      "value": 100,
      "density": {
        "enable": true,
        "value_area":1000
      }
    },
    "color": {
      "value": ["#aa73ff", "#f8c210", "#83d238", "#33b1f8"]
    },

    "shape": {
      "type": "circle",
      "stroke": {
        "width": 0,
        "color": "#fff"
      },
      "polygon": {
        "nb_sides": 5
      },
      "image": {
        "src": "img/github.svg",
        "width": 100,
        "height": 100
      }
    },
    "opacity": {
      "value": 0.6,
      "random": false,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 1,
        "opacity_min": 0.1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "size": {
      "value": 2,
      "random": true,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 40,
        "size_min": 0.1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "line_linked": {
      "enable": true,
      "distance": 120,
      "color": "#ffffff",
      "opacity": 0.4,
      "width": 1
    },
  },
  "interactivity": {
    "detect_on": "canvas",
    "events": {
      "onhover": {
        "enable": true,
        "mode": "grab"
      },
      "onclick": {
        "enable": false
      },
      "resize": true
    },
    "modes": {
      "grab": {
        "distance": 140,
        "line_linked": {
          "opacity": 1
        }
      },
      "bubble": {
        "distance": 400,
        "size": 40,
        "duration": 2,
        "opacity": 8,
        "speed": 3
      },
      "repulse": {
        "distance": 200,
        "duration": 0.4
      },
      "push": {
        "particles_nb": 4
      },
      "remove": {
        "particles_nb": 2
      }
    }
  },
  "retina_detect": false
});
```

Portfolio js (here is the code)

```
$(window).on("load resize", function () {
        $('#loader-overlay').fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $(this).remove();
        });

        var $container2 = $('.isotope'),
                colWidth = function () {
                    var w = $container2.width(),
                            columnNum = 1,
                            columnWidth = 0;

                    if ($('#even-grid').length > 0) {
                        if (w > 1040) {
                            columnNum = 4;
                        } else if (w > 850) {
                            columnNum = 4;
                        } else if (w > 768) {
                            columnNum = 2;
                        } else if (w > 480) {
                            columnNum = 2;
                        } else if (w > 300) {
                            columnNum = 1;
                        }
                    } else if ($('#masonry-grid-3').length > 0) {
                        if (w > 1040) {
                            columnNum = 3;
                        } else if (w > 850) {
                            columnNum = 3;
                        } else if (w > 768) {
                            columnNum = 2;
                        } else if (w > 480) {
                            columnNum = 2;
                        } else if (w > 300) {
                            columnNum = 1;
                        }
                    } else if ($('#masonry-grid-4').length > 0) {
                        if (w > 1040) {
                            columnNum = 4;
                        } else if (w > 850) {
                            columnNum = 4;
                        } else if (w > 768) {
                            columnNum = 2;
                        } else if (w > 480) {
                            columnNum = 2;
                        } else if (w > 300) {
                            columnNum = 1;
                        }
                    } else if ($('#even-grid-5').length > 0) {
                        if (w > 1040) {
                            columnNum = 5;
                        } else if (w > 850) {
                            columnNum = 5;
                        } else if (w > 768) {
                            columnNum = 4;
                        } else if (w > 480) {
                            columnNum = 2;
                        } else if (w > 300) {
                            columnNum = 1;
                        }
                    } else if ($('#even-grid-3').length > 0) {
                        if (w > 1040) {
                            columnNum = 3;
                        } else if (w > 850) {
                            columnNum = 3;
                        } else if (w > 768) {
                            columnNum = 2;
                        } else if (w > 480) {
                            columnNum = 2;
                        } else if (w > 300) {
                            columnNum = 1;
                        }
                    } else if ($('#masonry-grid-5').length > 0) {
                        if (w > 1040) {
                            columnNum = 5;
                        } else if (w > 850) {
                            columnNum = 5;
                        } else if (w > 768) {
                            columnNum = 4;
                        } else if (w > 480) {
                            columnNum = 2;
                        } else if (w > 300) {
                            columnNum = 1;
                        }
                    }

                    columnWidth = Math.floor(w / columnNum);

                    //Default item width and height
                    $container2.find('.item-img').each(function () {
                        var $item = $(this),
                                width = columnWidth,
                                height = columnWidth;
                        $item.css({
                            width: width,
                            height: height
                        });
                    });

                    //2x width item width and height
                    $container2.find('.width2').each(function () {
                        var $item = $(this),
                                width = columnWidth * 2,
                                height = columnWidth;
                        if (w <= 480) {
                            width = columnWidth;
                        }
                        $item.css({
                            width: width,
                            height: height
                        });
                    });

                    //2x height item width and height
                    $container2.find('.height2').each(function () {
                        var $item = $(this),
                                width = columnWidth,
                                height = columnWidth * 2;
                        $item.css({
                            width: width,
                            height: height
                        });
                    });

                    //2x item width and height
                    $container2.find('.width2.height2').each(function () {
                        var $item = $(this),
                                width = columnWidth * 2,
                                height = columnWidth * 2;
                        $item.css({
                            width: width,
                            height: height
                        });
                    });
                    return columnWidth;
                },
                $container2 = $('.isotope').isotope({
            resizable: true,
            itemSelector: '.item-img',
            masonry: {
                columnWidth: colWidth(),
                gutterWidth: 10
            }
        });

        /*
         Portfolio Filter using Isotope
         */

        $('.gallery-filter').on('click', 'li', function () {
            $('.gallery-filter li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
            $container2.isotope({
                filter: filterValue
            });
        });

    });
```

Comment: Please add code in your question to get better help.

Comment: View the source code, is too long to paste it.

Comment: Have you included jquery/js file?

Comment: If it's too long to paste it, your question is too broad.

Comment: @KamranJabbar 
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/particles.min.js" ></script>
 <script src="js/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/index.js"></script>
 <script src="js/master.js"></script>
 <script src="js/smoothscroll.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed --> 
 <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

Comment: @DarthJDG Maybe if you check, find the answer. All files are included, they are only started from smartphones or if the browser size decreases.

Comment: Please check console to check the errors.

Comment: @KamranJabbar i haven't error in my console.

Answer (score 0):

without the code, it is not easy to fix, well you could fix it with a hack

```
window.onload = function(){ window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize')); };
```

but fixing your code would be a better solution.